# Clang-format align AlignConsecutiveAssignments breaks when line longer than ColumnLimit

Tags: c++, clang-format

AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true 
ColumnLimit: 80

With the following code (C++) clang-format formats this to be:

```
testANameText = functionWithLongNameA(parameterOne, parameterTwo,
                                      parameterThree, parameterFour);
testBText = functionWithLongNameA(parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree,
                                  parameterFour);
testCLongNameText = functionWithLongNameC(parameterOne, parameterTwo,
                                          parameterThree, parameterFour);
```

I'd expect something to be formatted like at least something like below, where the assignment operators are aligned.

```
testANameText     = functionWithLongNameA(parameterOne, parameterTwo,
                                          parameterThree, parameterFour);
testBText         = functionWithLongNameA(parameterOne, parameterTwo, 
                                          parameterThree, parameterFour);
testCLongNameText = functionWithLongNameC(parameterOne, parameterTwo,
                                          parameterThree, parameterFour);
```

Is this possible? Perhaps I'm missing an option?

Answer (score 0):

`AlignConsecutiveAssignments` argument in not a boolean

setting it to `Consecutive` should do the trick

see more options in [the docs](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)